# How can I create a "container" where I can place multiple widgets inside?

Tags: awesome-wm

I have textclock, systray and seperator widgets I would like to place in a container.
Then, I will put that container on my topbar and create keys to show/hide the container..

But being new to this I'm not sure how to make the container. I found helpful examples to create the widgets I needed as I wanted them, but I'm not sure about putting them all in a container widget.

Answer (score 0):

The API documentation has a couple of elements under `wibox.container` and `wibox.layout`: https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/

In AWesomeWM, a "container" is something that contains just a single other widget. You want a layout.

Most likely, you want a fixed layout, which is a layout that just puts the widgets next to each other: https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/classes/wibox.layout.fixed.html